# QT - qtwebsocket - can't connect

Tags: qt, websocket

I'm using qtwebsocket from https://github.com/antlafarge/QtWebsocket on QT Creator 5.0, Linux 64bit. I'm trying connect to echo test:

wsSocket->connectToHost( "echo.websocket.org", 80 );

But I immediately get disconnected status. I tried also with ws:// and http:// prefix but same error. Any idea? I even don't know how to report a bug on this gitorious.

It is important to me to don't use webkit, I need pure TCP socket connection.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly looking at the example located:

https://github.com/antlafarge/QtWebsocket/tree/master/Example

I don't know the state of the project too well, but it looks like there is still a to-do list on what it can do; one item I noticed, it says WSS is not yet supported.

Try running both sides of the Client and Server in the included example, and see if you can get a connection in that context before trying the echo.websocket.org server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: [Update] The project has been moved to https://gitorious.org/qt/qtwebsockets and now fully supports secure websockets.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Qt websockets add-on module located at https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebsockets.
It has been tested on several platforms, and successfully succeeds with the AutoBahn Testsuite.